# Need help in display tree structure using Ractive js

Tags: javascript, php, jstree, ractivejs

I am new to Ractive js. 
I need to display organisational hierarchy in a form of tree.
I have 1 array defined in my Ractive template.

```
managerTeam = {M1: [T1, T2, M2, T3], M2: [M3, T4,T5],  M3: [T6,T7]};
```

where `M1` is the root manager, `T1-T7` are leaf nodes (team members)

How should I display it using `jsTree` or any other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use jsTree you will have to:

1. add `jsTree` library to your page
2. turn your `managerTeam` object into format acceptable for `jsTree`, like this:

`managerTeam = [{ "id":"m1", "text": "M1", "children": [ {"parent": "m1", "text": "T1"}, {"parent": "m1", "text": "T2"}, {"parent": "m1", "text": "M2"}, {"parent": "m1", "text": "T3"} ], "state":{"opened":true}}, { "parent": "root", "id": "m2", "text": "M2", "children": [ {"parent": "m2", "text": "M3"}, {"parent": "m2", "text": "T4"}, {"parent": "m2", "text": "T5"} ], "state":{"opened":true}},  { "id": "m3", "text": "M3", "children": [ {"parent": "m3", "text": "T6"}, {"parent": "m3", "text": "T7"} ], "state":{"opened":true}}]`

3. write some configuration code for the div on your page that will be turned into tree according to `jsTree` rules and run it after DOM is loaded

An example of that you can see here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/2t8pdLoz/)